# What is the "curl --tlsv1" equivalent for PHP

Tags: php, bash, curl

Does anyone know the answer to this question? I read PHP cURL documentation but I could not find an answer.
I have a bash script and I want to convert it to PHP. I just can't figure out what is the equivalent of

```
curl --tlsv1
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` option, with the `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1` value.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more information.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot @LeonardChallis. I don't know how I missed that! :)